# How to reduce an array of objects by search term

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of products and I'm looking to create a new array if the product title or product tags list contains a search term.

Below is a simplified version.

```
const products = [{title: 'apple-green', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]},
                      {title: 'orange', tags: [{colour: 'orange', tagType: 'colour'}]},
                      {title: 'cherry', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]},
                      {title: 'pear', tags: [{colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour'}]}]

const searchTerm = "green"

const result = [{title: 'apple-green', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'},
                {title: 'pear', tags: [{colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour'}]}]
```

I thinking that using reduce would be the best way to achieve this.

I have tried the below without success.

```js
const result = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
  if (product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || 
      product.tags.map((tag) => 
        tag.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))) 
    return product

  return [acc, ...product]
}, [])
```

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: *I have tried the below without success* **is not a helpful problem/error description**.

Comment: Your written language says "equal a search term" but your logic seems to be "includes a search term"

Comment: *"I thinking that using reduce would be the best way to achieve this."* No, `reduce` isn't the best way to filter an array. `filter` (or a loop) is the best way to filter an array. `reduce` is designed for Functional Programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. IMHO (but it's not just me), using it outside of that realm is an anti-pattern. Just use a loop or (in cases like this) a more specific function like `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is probably the correct function for this rather than `Array#reduce`, since no transformation appears to be applied to the output structure (and even if it were, `map`/`filter` may be clearer than `reduce`).

After writing a helper function to perform a case-insensitive substring/includes check, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on `product.tags` to determine if any of the `tag.colour` properties from a product's tags array match the search term.

```js
const products = [{title: 'apple-green', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]}, {title: 'orange', tags: [{colour: 'orange', tagType: 'colour'}]}, {title: 'cherry', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]}, {title: 'pear', tags: [{colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour'}]}];

const includesAnyCase = (s, t) => s.toLowerCase().includes(t.toLowerCase());

const filterProducts = (products, searchTerm) =>
  products.filter(product =>
    includesAnyCase(product.title, searchTerm) || 
    product.tags.some(tag => includesAnyCase(tag.colour, searchTerm))
  )
;

console.log(filterProducts(products, "green"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
result = products.filter(product => {
  return product.title.toLowerCase()includes.(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        || product.tags.includes({colour: searchTerm.toLowerCase(), tagType: 'colour'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` twice for brevity, though `filter` seems a more natural fit:

```js
const products = [
  { title: 'apple-green', tags: [{ colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour' }] },
  { title: 'apple-red', tags: [{ colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour' }] },
  { title: 'orange', tags: [{ colour: 'orange', tagType: 'colour' }] },
  { title: 'cherry', tags: [{ colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour' }] },
  { title: 'pear', tags: [{ colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour' }] }
];

const searchTerm = "green";

const results = products.reduce((matchingProducts, currentProduct) => {
  const matchingColoured = currentProduct.tags.reduce((p, c) => {
    return c.colour === searchTerm ? [c, ...p] : null;
  }, []);
  return matchingColoured ? [currentProduct, ...matchingProducts] : matchingProducts;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, {}, 4));
```

Outputs:

````js
[
    {
        "title": "pear",
        "tags": [
            {
                "colour": "green",
                "tagType": "colour"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "apple-green",
        "tags": [
            {
                "colour": "green",
                "tagType": "colour"
            }
        ]
    }
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.prototype.filter() function to accept only the products with titles that contain the search term or with tags that `===` the searchTerm. Of course you can use `.includes` on the tags as well if that is what you wish.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DariusM/y1u4cedk/1/

```
const products = [
  {title: 'apple-green', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]},
  {title: 'orange', tags: [{colour: 'orange', tagType: 'colour'}]},
  {title: 'cherry', tags: [{colour: 'red', tagType: 'colour'}]},
  {title: 'pear', tags: [{colour: 'green', tagType: 'colour'}]}
 ];

const searchTerm = "green"

const result = products.filter((product) => {
  if(product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
    return true;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < product.tags.length; i++){
    if(product.tags[i][product.tags[i].tagType] === searchTerm){
        return true;
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```